# Manipulating drop-down based on data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I like to create scripts that are clear as to what they do, I like comment, and use `data- *` in HTML to define what each component is.

I created a script that creates a dropdown, that I can open and close. The result:

```js
/*!
 * Script needed to control the dropdown with the heading options in the new e-mail page
 *
 */
'use strict';
var EmailToggle = {
 init: function() {
  this.dropdown    = $('[data-dropdown]');
  this.dropdownChildren = $('[data-dropdown]').children();
  this.dropdownStatus  = $('[data-dropdown]').data('status');
  this.dropdownButton  = $('[data-dropdown-to]');

  this.activeClass = 'email__dropdown--active';

  /*!
   * Checks if the value of data-dropdown is true, if it is, the script can continue.
   *
   */
  if (this.dropdown.data('dropdown')) {
   this.dropdownButton.bind('click', this._filter.bind(this));
   this.dropdownChildren.bind('click', this._filter.bind(this));
  }
 },

 /*!
  * Key point to decide whether the dropdown will appear or hide depending on your own value. 
  * If the vaue of data-status is not open, then the {Function} _showDropdown will be called, 
  * otherwise the {Function} _hideDropdown will be called.
  *
  */
 _filter: function() {
  if (this.dropdownStatus !== 'open') {
   this._showDropdown();
   return;
  } 

  this._hideDropdown();
 },

 /*!
  * More than show or hide the sidebar, these two {Function} will be required to make changes in nested variables 
  * and data-* available, to switch between them.
  *
  */
 _showDropdown: function() {
  this.dropdownButton
   .attr('data-dropdown-to', this.dropdownStatus);

  this.dropdownStatus = 'open';
  this.dropdown
   .attr('data-status', this.dropdownStatus)
   .addClass(this.activeClass)
   .show();
 },

 _hideDropdown: function() {
  this.dropdownButton
   .attr('data-dropdown-to', this.dropdownStatus);

  this.dropdownStatus = 'close';
  this.dropdown
   .attr('data-status', 'close')
   .removeClass(this.activeClass)
   .hide();
 }
};

EmailToggle.init();
```

```css
  .email__option {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #E5E6E7;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: #333333;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    transition: ease 0.5s;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    user-select: none; }
    .email__option:hover {
      border-color: #E97228; }
    .email__option--bold {
      font-weight: bold; }
    .email__option--italic {
      font-style: italic; }
    .email__option--underline {
      padding-bottom: 3px;
      text-decoration: underline; }
      .email__option--underline:hover {
        text-decoration: underline; }
    .email__option.wysihtml5-command-active {
      border-color: #E97228; }
  .email__dropdown {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #E97228;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute; }
    .email__dropdown-option {
      color: #333333;
      display: block;
      padding-bottom: 2px;
      padding-top: 2px;
      text-decoration: none; }
    .email__dropdown--active {
      display: inline-block; }
  .email__upload {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    position: relative; }
  .email__attachment--file {
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; }
  .email__editor {
    border: none;
    color: #000000;
    height: 250px;
    outline: none;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="email__option email__option--dropdown" data-dropdown-to="open">
                      <span>Tamanho</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="email__dropdown" data-dropdown="dropdown" data-status="close" aria-hidden="true">
                      <a class="email__dropdown-option">Tamanho h1</a>
                      <a class="email__dropdown-option">Tamanho h2</a>
                      <a class="email__dropdown-option">Tamanho h3</a>
                      <a class="email__dropdown-option">Tamanho h4</a>
                      <a class="email__dropdown-option">Tamanho h5</a>
                      <a class="email__dropdown-option">Tamanho h6</a>
                    </div>
```

What do you think of the script and how I'm doing things? Can I improve it?

How I can improve this script?

Comment: it looks nice, however with this being a select, shouldn't it be possible to actually select something, mark one/multiple as selected, then when shown have them highlighted/circled?

Comment: is that compiled Sass?

Comment: `email__attachment--file` suggests file is a state that attachment can be in, whereas it's probably a type of attachment, `email__attachment-file` would be closer to correct BEM, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks pretty clean for me. Is easy to follow and the actions and responsibilities are correctly splitter.

You can make some more related to a constructor-object, instead of use a literal object.[check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20724533/difference-between-adding-function-to-prototype-and-object-literal-in-javascript).

Also, you are using a weird looking nomenclature with `_`. I guessing you are try to make some kind of private function. Winch have sense,you can make something more near to private with [scope functions](http://lupomontero.com/using-javascript-closures-to-create-private-scopes/).

Your code comments, doesn't look like a jsdoc, please, consider use a common standard: http://usejsdoc.org/

You are using a weird class name mixed  `_` and `--` try to use something unified, the more common standard is `-` btw spaces.

the last one, and less anoying, please use:

```
  .email__upload {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
  } //<-- same as functions.
```

instead of:

```
  .email__upload {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative; } //<--plz don't
```